# Permission error when post message to wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the following error when post to fb feed when using POST. It's working fine with GET method. Is there any permission needed to add.

> ```
> message: '(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\\n          either publish_to_groups
> ```
>
> permission with user token, or both manage_pages \\n          and
>   publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\n
>   requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \\n
>   sufficient administrative permission, I20191112-19:45:36.182(5.5)?
>   type: OAuthException, I20191112-19:45:36.182(5.5)?      code: 200,
>   I20191112-19:45:36.183(5.5)?      fbtrace_id: AJbuFD_SHxv-s8iOWWyZIVg
>   }

```
 graph.post("me/feed", wallPost, function(err, res) {

          console.log(res); // { id: xxxxx}
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to post to your own feed, on your user profile? That is not possible any more, the necessary permissions have been removed a while ago. If that’s not it - well then actually _read_ the error message, it already tells you what is missing if you are trying to post to a group or page.

Comment: I am not psoting any group or page. I need to post to authenticated user's wall itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publishing to a user profile is not possible anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24

You can only use [Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) Options, but there is no API for it with `publish_actions` being gone.